# Iot Core drops Wifi when trying to get signal bars/strength, after some success

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm running into a strange issue. I want to get the Wifi signal bars periodically and update a small display. I have tried running it in code and using the API. Both will run for awhile but after some time, maybe 30 minutes the Iot default app displays no network information. If I go into settings and click "Network & Wi-Fi" the device will hang and will need to be hard reset.

I thought that maybe I was scanning too quickly so I changed the timer to be every one minute but still have this issue. It could be an issue with my approach, maybe there's a cleaner way to get this signal information without a scan? I'm running Windows Iot Core v.10.0.16299.309 on a Raspberry Pi3. This is my code.

Called from Run

```
ThreadPoolTimer UpdateWifiSignalTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
        {
            WifiSignal();
        }, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Attempt 1

```
if (WiFiAdapter != null)
        {
            networkAddapterId = WiFiAdapter.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId.ToString();
            await WiFiAdapter.ScanAsync();

            if (WiFiAdapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync() != null)
            {
                var connectedProfile = await WiFiAdapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync();
                if (connectedProfile != null && !connectedProfile.ProfileName.Equals(savedProfileName))
                {
                    savedProfileName = connectedProfile.ProfileName;
                    wifiProfile.Add( new WifiProfile { MacAddress = networkAddapterId, Ssid = savedProfileName }) ;
                }
            }

            var wifiPoint = new List<WiFiSignal>();
            WiFiNetworkReport report = WiFiAdapter.NetworkReport;

            foreach (var availableNetwork in report.AvailableNetworks)
            {
                WiFiSignal wifiSignal = new WiFiSignal()
                {
                    MacAddress = availableNetwork.Bssid,
                    Ssid = availableNetwork.Ssid,
                    SignalBars = availableNetwork.SignalBars,
                    ChannelCenterFrequencyInKilohertz = availableNetwork.ChannelCenterFrequencyInKilohertz,
                    NetworkKind = availableNetwork.NetworkKind.ToString(),
                    PhysicalKind = availableNetwork.PhyKind.ToString(),
                    Encryption = availableNetwork.SecuritySettings.NetworkEncryptionType.ToString()
                };

                wifiPoint.Add(wifiSignal);
            }

            int bars = 0;
            foreach (var localNetworks in wifiPoint)
            {
                if (localNetworks.Ssid == savedProfileName)
                {
                    bars = localNetworks.SignalBars;
                    display.ClearDisplayBuf();
                }
            }
```

Attempt 2

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (interfaceGUID == null)
            {
                using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("http://{0}:8080/api/wifi/interfaces", DeviceName)))
                {

                    request.Headers.Authorization = CreateBasicCredentials("Administrator", PASSWORD);
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                    {
                        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var interfaces = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AvailableInterfaces>(data);
                        var ourInterface = interfaces.Interfaces.First();
                        interfaceGUID = ourInterface.GUID.Replace('{', ' ').Replace('}', ' ').Trim();
                    }
                }
            }

            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("http://{0}:8080/api/wifi/networks?interface={1}", DeviceName, interfaceGUID)))
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = CreateBasicCredentials("Administrator", PASSWORD);
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var networks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AvailableNetworksObject>(data);
                    this.Networks = networks.AvailableNetworks;

                    //this.Status = "Refresh Wifi Succeeded";
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in this.Networks)
            {
                if (item.AlreadyConnected == true)
                {
                    display.ClearDisplayBuf();
                    display.WriteLineDisplayBuf(item.SignalQuality.ToString(), 0, 0);
                    display.DisplayUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have tested with the code you provided,but commented `display.ClearDisplayBuf();`, the issue could not be reproduced. Could you please provide more detailed code about `display`?

Comment: I have a Case statement after this code that takes the number of bars and sets an icon image on a SSD1306 oled display. I placed that ClearDisplayBuf method there so that I wouldn't need to repeat it in each case. I can't see this causing the wireless adapter to drop.